# Can't import java.util.Scanner

Tags: java, methods, import, java.util.scanner

I have been trying to create program that lets a user input a number of eggs to buy and calculates the price. I have tried using the scanner method to input the integer, but I can't seem to import the scanner method.

Here's what I have:

```
package eggsorder;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.IOException;


public class EggsOrder {
static final double EGGS_DOZEN   = 7.25;
static final double EGGS_SINGLE = 0.75;
static final int DOZEN_NUMBER = 12;

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    System.out.println("Enter number of eggs for purchase: ");   
    Scanner enter = new Scanner(System.in);
    int eggs = enter.nextInt();
    System.out.println("You ordered " + eggs + "eggs.");
    System.out.println("That is " + (eggs / DOZEN_NUMBER) + " dozen eggs     at 7.25 per dozen and " + (eggs % DOZEN_NUMBER) + " additional eggs at 0.75 each");
    System.out.println("Which is a total price of "  + (((eggs % DOZEN_NUMBER) * EGGS_SINGLE) + ((eggs / DOZEN_NUMBER) * EGGS_DOZEN)));
```

This is the error I get after running:

```
java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Uncompilable source code - cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class Scanner
  location: class java.util
at eggsorder.EggsOrder.<clinit>(EggsOrder.java:7)
```

The code works without the scanner method, but it needs to use it.

I have tried using java.util and various other variations but to no avail.

Also, I am using the latest version of NetBeans and java

Comment: which tool you run java program? netbeans or eclipse?

Comment: Do you have errors anywhere else in your source code?  Does the import statement `import java.util.Scanner` give you an error?

Comment: It might help to run a clean or clear all cached files manually - especially if your code compiles fine from command line (have you tried that?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you are using an IDE (like Netbeans or eclipse) which allows you to run the `code` even if certain `classes` are not `compilable`. During the application's runtime, if you access this `class` it would lead to this exception.

Solution :- Simply Clean Your Project and Build and Run Then Again.

Comment: This solved it
It seemed making a new project entirely and copying the code over solved the problem.

It appears that saving the .java file into a different folder, as well as in the source folder, creates the scanner error.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have configured PATH, CLASSPATH and JAVA_HOME variable in system Environment variable.
1) It might refers older version of java then 1.5 
or 
2) May be not added PATH,CLASSPATH, JAVA_HOME variable there.

BTW Your code is works fine in my Eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

Try unchecking the "Compile on save" setting in Build -> Compiling.

Source: http://forums.netbeans.org/post-45324.html

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/11574669)

Comment: Oh, sorry about that! I'll keep that in mind. Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

you can try this

```
java.util.Scanner enter = new  java.util.Scanner(System.in);
```

i tested your code and it seems to import correctly on my end. Maybe something is wrong with your IDE try resetting it

Comment: Even after adding that in it still says in can not find the scanner symbol.