# how to import java.util.Scanner

Tags: java, eclipse, oop, java.util.scanner

I'm new to Java, and I'm stuck as to why I'm getting an error message whenever I import java.util.Scanner.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        
        System.out.println("What is your name? ");
        String name = scanner.nextLine();
        
        System.out.println("Hello "+name);
        
        
    }

}
```

On Line 1, I'm getting an error message saying "The type java.util.Iterator cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files".
When I run it, the console says, "Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem:

at Main.main(Main.java:5)".

I'm using the Eclipse IDE.
If anyone can help, I would appreciate it. Thank you

Comment: Try this maybe: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35909160/cant-import-java-util-scanner/35909236

Answer (score 0):

Check if you have JRE in your project.
`Project`>`Properties`>`Java Build Path`>`JRE System Library`.

Comment: When I go to Java Build Path, inside of Modulepath, I have JavaSE-16. So yes, I do have JRE system library.

Comment: I haven't written in JavaSE-16 before. Maybe try downgrading to 15 or 14, then click apply. Sometimes, you also need to refresh your project in order for changes to take effect.

Answer (score 0):

Eclipse can't 'read' your JRE, as in, it can't find even something as simple as `java.lang.String`. This is because either you've misconfigured the JRE, or the JRE you configured is not understandable by eclipse.

Note that eclipse still uses the terminology 'JRE', eventhough JREs no longer exist. When eclipse tells you 'please point me at a JRE', it's really saying: "Please point me at a JDK".

JDK16 is quite new, your eclipse is probably outdated and can't read it. Either be on the cutting edge with all the things, or take stable versions for all the things. Don't mix and match.

### Option 1: Downgrade Java.

So, install e.g. adoptopenJDK's JDK11, then tell eclipse about it (Window -> preferences -> search in the filterbar for JRE -> add a new one -> Point at the JDK11 install dir, or possibly its "Home" subdir if on mac), and set up your project to use that (right click, properties, you'll find it from there). It's no problem to have both JDK16 and JDK11 installed on a single machine. You can tell eclipse about all of em and pick a JDK to use for each project and even each run/debug.

### Option 2: Upgrade your eclipse

The current most recent stable version should be fine.

NOTE: This problem has nothing to do with Scanner specifically. It won't even find `java.lang.String` - it will fail the first time you use any core type in your source file.

Answer (score 0):

Please check if jdk's bin path is there in your path environment variable. Also, JAVA_HOME is also set in your environment variable.